# Allow only Service Account to Execute block of Code to Decrypt Column Level Values in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, encryption, permissions, sql-server-2019, sql-grant

We have implemented Column level encryption on CON_String column which has username/password based connection strings. We have been using following code in order to see the decrypted column values

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY AdventureSymmetricKey 
DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE AdventureCertificate

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(2000), DecryptByKey(CON_String)) as 'Decrypted_Con_String'
FROM   dbo.Connection_Details

CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY AdventureSymmetricKey
```

as of now all the developers are able to run this block of code and see the decrypted values. Our ask is it allow only **Service-Dev-Acc** to be able to execute this query running through a scheduled job and no one else should be able to execute the above query to see the output.

We tried with following to **GRANT** access to Service-Dev-Acc

```
GRANT CONTROL ON SYMMETRIC KEY::AdventureSymmetricKey TO Service-Dev-Acc;
GRANT CONTROL ON CERTIFICATE::AdventureCertificate TO Service-Dev-Acc;
GRANT VIEW DEFINATION ON SYMMETRIC KEY::AdventureSymmetricKey TO Service-Dev-Acc;
GRANT VIEW DEFINATION ON CERTIFICATE::AdventureCertificate TO Service-Dev-Acc;
```

**DENY** everyone else

```
DENY CONTROL ON SYMMETRIC KEY::AdventureSymmetricKey TO PUBLIC;
DENY CONTROL ON CERTIFICATE::AdventureCertificate TO PUBLIC;
DENY VIEW DEFINATION ON SYMMETRIC KEY::AdventureSymmetricKey TO PUBLIC;
DENY VIEW DEFINATION ON CERTIFICATE::AdventureCertificate TO PUBLIC;
```

Although after doing this all the developers are able to run the DecryptByKey code to see the decrypted values.

I do not want to implement row level security, views, table valued function with EXECUTE AS USER solution. I want to control using GRANT/ DENY (Access Control) in SQL Server.

Comment: Just a guess, but they probably need to logout first before the rights work, an open key will be valid in the session

Comment: @siggemannen- tried this option still it works after logout

Comment: "DEFINATION" , is that really what you ran?

Comment: What kind of rights do your "developers" have? sysadmin? If i create a user without rights, it cannot access the keys, so i'm betting your users have too many rights already

Comment: I suggest you use [Always Encrypted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017). This feature encrypt/decrypt at **client** level and require a certificate installed on the machine. Only the machine(s) with the certificate can encrypt/decrypt data

Answer (score 0):

- Create a role called `"Decryptor"` and grant  `SELECT` on the `symmetric key and certificate` used to `encrypt` the column + `EXECUTE` on the `stored procedure` that contains the `DecryptByKey` function
- Add the `Service-Dev-Acc` account to the `Decryptor role`
- `Deny` all users the ability to `SELECT` from the column that is encrypted

  ```
    CREATE ROLE Decryptor;
    GRANT SELECT ON SYMMETRIC KEY AdventureSymmetricKey TO Decryptor;
    GRANT SELECT ON CERTIFICATE AdventureCertificate TO Decryptor;
    GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.DecryptByKey TO Decryptor;
    ALTER USER Service-Dev-Acc ADD MEMBER Decryptor;
    DENY SELECT ON dbo.Connection_Details(CON_String) TO PUBLIC;
  ```

only users who are members of the `Decryptor role` will be able to `execute` the block of code to `decrypt` the column level values.